# Retrive Data between Two Varchar Dates from MySql

Tags: mysql, date

Hello I am Using Mysql Database.i have one table Employee.
Employee Table Description Given Below.

```
Emp_id int(10),emp_name varchar(255),dob varchar(120)
```

and i store employee dob in

```
dd-MMM-yyyy formate (21-May-1990)
```

now i want to all employee whose dob is between 01-May-1990 to 31-May-1990.

Kindly let me know how to get data between two varchar date

I have edit My question. My date formate is "dd-MMM-yyyy".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the values are stored as string, you need to convert it. MySQL has a built in function called [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

```
SELECT Emp_id, emp_name
FROM TableName
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dob,'%d-%M-%Y') >= '1990-05-01'
       AND STR_TO_DATE(dob,'%d-%M-%Y') <= '1990-05-31'
```

However, using function on a column doesn't use any index and will decrease performance especially on large tables. A good solution is to use the correct datatype `Date`  and create an index on it.

Comment: i am using dd-MMM-yyyy this formate  and date stored as 21-May-1990 formate.

Comment: @JavaMan yep you mentioned that. Its corresponding format that the function knows is `%d-%M-%Y`. You can see more on this [LINK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: .dob stored as 21-May-1990 formate and u gave solution like WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dob,'%d-%M-%Y') >= '1990-05-01'
       AND STR_TO_DATE(dob,'%d-%M-%Y') <= '1990-05-31'. i have tried it, but cant get result

Comment: @JavaMan maybe there is something wrong with your data. I have a [working solution on this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a79ef/2).

Comment: last question, do you have leading zero for days less than 10? example, `08-May-1990` ***if not***, use the following format: ***`%e-%M-%Y`***:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77859/discussion-between-java-man-and-john-woo).

Comment: @JavaMan then use `STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%e-%M-%Y')`

Comment: Will you please provide full query ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the char to a date using `STR_TO_DATE`

```
SELECT * from employee where STR_TO_DATE(dob,'%d-%M-%y') between '01.05.1990' and '31.05.1990'
```

But why you store your date as string? You should store it as a date.

Answer (score 1):

Use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert the strings to the DateTime data type [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
SELECT Emp_id, emp_name, don
FROM employee   WHERE str_to_date(dob, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN str_to_date('01-May-1990', '%m/%d/%Y') AND str_to_date('31-May-1990', '%m/%d/%Y')
```